Is trauma to the abdominal wall classed as somatic pain or visceral pain?
I'm writing a fictional story set in the real world with fight scenes in it. If I understood correctly after doing some research, abdominal wall trauma should be classed as somatic pain if the wall is properly tensed to receive impacts. But if it isn't, then it should count as visceral pain due to penetration into the internal organs. Is that correct?
Specifically, I want to write a scene involving two trained martial artists. I'd assume body shots should be described with symptoms of somatic pain (stinging, burning, aching) until one fighter becomes too tired to flex properly, at which point, I should include symptoms of visceral pain (aching, stretching, squeezing, nausea). Am I on the right track?
And are there any other details I should be made aware of? Thanks!

I think you're over-thinking this. There's so much overlap in the descriptions of pain that it doesn't really fit nicely into those categories. Note, for example, that you listed "aching" under both categories. To distinguish I think most people understand the word "visceral" to mean a deeper, more intense pain and that might be enough.

I agree with the comment above. Pain is pain. There are techniques examiners use to differentiate between abdominal wall pain and visceral pain, but I don't expect patients to know the difference, especially with trauma.
